# Custom module beforesave() issue in backend

Tags: magento-1.7

I have create a custom module and it has custom table for an model.In the resource model file i am try to validated  with old data.

`issue,` in admin panel i was try to edit  and save the exiting data  **but it always show  This Vendor UserName already exists**   due to not getting  **vendor_id (the primary key of table)** of 
this below code...

```
if ($vendor->getVendorId()) {
        $bind['vendor_id'] = (int)$vendor->getVendorId();
        $select->where('vendor_id != :vendor_id');
    }
```

here Vendor_id already exit.

Here the my mysql4 resource file

```
<?php
class Amit_Vendor_Model_Mysql4_Vendor extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        $this->_init('vendor/vendor', 'vendor_id');
    }


    /**
     * Check customer by id
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkVendorId($vendorId)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $bind    = array('vendor_id' => (int)$vendorId);
        $select  = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), 'vendor_id')
            ->where('vendor_id = :vendor_id')
            ->limit(1);

        $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /* check vendor email id exits or not
    * if not exits then thrown exception
    */
    protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $vendor){

        parent::_beforeSave($vendor);
        if(!$vendor->getEmail()){
            throw Mage::Exception('Amit_Vendor',Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor email is required'));
        }
        if(!$vendor->getUserName()){
            throw Mage::Exception('Amit_Vendor',Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor User is required'));
        }
        $this->checkforBefore($vendor);
        $adapter=$this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $bind=array('email'=>$vendor->getEmail());
         $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), array('email'))
            ->where('email = :email');

            if ($vendor->getVendorId()) {
            $bind['vendor_id'] = (int)$vendor->getVendorId();
            $select->where('vendor_id != :vendor_id');
        }

        $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($result) {
            throw Mage::exception(
                'Amit_Vendor', Mage::helper('vendor')->__('This Vendor email already exists'),
                Amit_Vendor_Model_Vendor::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
            );
        }
         return $this;

    }
    protected function checkforBefore(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $vendor){

        $adapter=$this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $bind=array('user_name'=>$vendor->getUserName());
         $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), array('user_name'))
            ->where('user_name = :user_name');

            if ($vendor->getVendorId()) {
            $bind['vendor_id'] = (int)$vendor->getVendorId();
            $select->where('vendor_id != :vendor_id');
        }

        $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($result) {
            throw Mage::exception(
                'Amit_Vendor', Mage::helper('vendor')->__('This Vendor UserName already exists'),
                Amit_Vendor_Model_Vendor::EXCEPTION_USERNAME_EXISTS
            );
        }
     return $this;
    }
    public function loadByEmail(Amit_Vendor_Model_Vendor $vendor, $email){
        $adpter=$this->_getReadAdapter();
        $bind=array('email'=>$email);
        $select=$adpter->select()
        ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), array('vendor_id'))
         ->where('email = :email');
          $vendorId = $adpter->fetchOne($select, $bind);

        if ($vendorId) {
            $this->load($vendor,$vendorId);
        } else {
            $vendor->setData(array());
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

and model file is

```
<?php
 class Amit_Vendor_Model_Vendor extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('vendor/vendor');
    }
     /**
     * Codes of exceptions related to vendor model
     */
    const EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD = 1;
    const EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS              = 2;
    const EXCEPTION_USERNAME_EXISTS       = 3;
   // const EXCEPTION_INVALID_RESET_PASSWORD_LINK_TOKEN = 4;
    /* validatating data */
    public function validate(){
        $error=array();
         if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getName(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor name  can\'t be empty');
        }
        if(!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(),'NotEmpty')){
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor email  can\'t be empty');
            }
         if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getUserName(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor Username  can\'t be empty');
        }
        if(!Zend_Validate::is($this->getMobileNo(),'NotEmpty')){
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor Mobile  can\'t be empty');

        }
         if (empty($errors)) {
            return true;
        }

        return $errors;
    }
    /**
     * Authenticate vendor
     *
     * @param  string $login
     * @param  string $password
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     * @return true
     *
     */
    public function authenticate($login, $password){
        $this->loadByEmail($login);
        if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
            );
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent('vendor_vendor_authenticated', array(
           'model'    => $this,
           'password' => $password,
        ));

        return true;
    }
    public function validatePassword($password){
        $pass=$this->getPassword();
        if(!$pass){
            return false;
        }
        if(!$password){
            return false;
        }

        if($pass==$password){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Load vendor by email
     *
     * @param   string $customerEmail
     * @return  Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function loadByEmail($vendoremail)
    {
        $this->_getResource()->loadByEmail($this,$vendoremail);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

My admin url is for save data is **vendor/adminhtml_vendor/save/id/2/key/93ff462dd3b29a4f5857e97a9601b4b6/**

```
**`Main issue is that i did not getting  primary value 2 from`** **getVendorId.**
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging / outputting the contents of getData on the $vendor model inside _beforeSave?

Comment: I was trying it in admin section of that modules...